# Update an object in the background based on the information saved in a rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have built a tiny Shiny app. First, in the same folder as the app, I saved a list whose elements are tibbles with information about people (one table per person). The code for that (run it first):

```
library(dplyr)
people <- list(john_smith = tibble(first_name = "John", last_name = "Smith",
                                   DOB = "2000-01-01"),
               mary_silver = tibble(first_name = "Mary", last_name = "Silver",
                                    DOB = "1999-12-12"))
saveRDS(people, file = "people.rds")
```

Below is the code for my Shiny app that is using that object. (Please ignore the code for the function that creates a handsontable; it's long because I copied it from somewhere else - I am new to handsontable - that's why it's so ugly and my headers are misbehaving).

Question: I would like to make changes in the table of one person (e.g., change the person's date of birth DOB) and then save those changes by hitting "Update Person Info" button on the left. As a result of that, I'd like the whole table for that person to be updated in the list 'people' and in the file 'people.rds'.
My challenge is: sever object 'output$person_table' contains the original information. Once changes are made in it - should I somehow change it in some other object? I am a bit lost with all that circularity.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
library(DT)

# Read in the existing people's list:
people <- readRDS("people.rds")

# Function to create an editable table in the app:
GetTablePersonInfo <- function(one_person_table){
    ### All columns are editable:
    editableCols <- 1:3
    sketch <- htmltools::withTags(table(
        tableHeader(one_person_table)
    ))
    datatable(one_person_table, 
              container = sketch,
              extensions = 'FixedHeader',
              class = "mytable nowrap hover row-border",
              rownames = F,
              escape = F,
              selection = list(mode = "none"),
              editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = 0)),
              options = list(pageLength = 10, server = F,
                             dom = 't',pagination = F,
                             ordering = F, autoWidth = F,  
                             scrollX = T, language.thousands = ",",
                             columnDefs = list(list(targets = editableCols - 1,
                                                    width = "100px"),
                                               list(targets = 0,
                                                    width = "30px")),
                             fixedHeader = T)) %>%
        formatStyle(editableCols, backgroundColor = '#eef6f6')
}

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
### ui code ####
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("My App"),

    # Sidebar with a pull-down to select a person:
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
              # Select the person:            
              selectizeInput("person_select", label = "Select Person",
                           choices = names(people), multiple = FALSE,
                           selected = names(people)[1]),
              # Update changes:
              actionButton("update_person", "Update Person Info")
        ),
        # Main panel with an editable table for the selected person:
        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("person_table")
        )
    )
)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
### server code ####
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Using my function 'GetTablePersonInfo' to grab the table for the person selected:
    output$person_table <- renderRHandsontable({
        person_name <- input$person_select
        person_table <- people[[person_name]]
        GetTablePersonInfo(one_person_table = person_table)
    })
}

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
### Run the app #### 
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you are rendering a rHandsontable using datatableoutput?

Comment: @SiddharthArthi Mostly because I thought one has more prettifying options with data table.